# vue plugin (learning) After publish or local test causes Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This is my first attempts of building a vuejs plugin and after much issues I have got closer to getting it to work, the latest issue gives no clues or idea as to what is missing or I need to do:

The code is for ["vue-autocompletion":"^1.0.7"](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/vue-autocompletion)

After I add this to a local project the app starts up fine but calling it on vue page:

```
<template>

<div>
  <vue-auto-completion
            @key-press="updateAutoCompleteItems"

            key-field="id" value-field="vehicleName"
            :items="vehicles" />

</div>
</template>
<script>
 import VueAutocompletion from 'vue-autocompletion'
 export default {
data () {
            return {
                vehicles:[{id:'a', vehicleName:'vehicle1'},{id:'a1', vehicleName:'vehicle2'},{id:'a2', vehicleName:'vehicle3'},{id:'a3', vehicleName:'vehicle3'}]
            }
        },
        components: {
            'vue-autocompletion':VueAutocompletion
        },
 methods: {

            updateAutoCompleteItems: function (searchValue) {

                    this.vehicles=[{id:'a0', name:'vehicle01'},{id:'a1', name:'vehicle02'},{id:'a2', name:'vehicle03'},{id:'a3', name:'vehicle03'}]

            },
        },

}
```

But when I launch site I get :

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <VueAutocompletion>
```

I read on another post about Vue.use
This has also been included - doesn't make a difference

```
import VueAutocompletion from 'vue-autocompletion'
Vue.use(VueAutocompletion);
```

Any help appreciated.

Just trying to understand about the manual way of doing a plugin.

E2A
Rather than add an answer. 
The resolution to this was to fix `webpack.config.js` to match and work with webpack version 4. There are lots of additional changes required & reason I was getting above message was due to mentioned file being incompletely configured.

[Webpack 3 `package.js`](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/vue-autocompletion/blob/a9ca746e8f701d63d0af0275135d13f1ebc22631/package.json)

[Webpack 3 `webpack.config.js`](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/vue-autocompletion/blob/a9ca746e8f701d63d0af0275135d13f1ebc22631/webpack.config.js)

[webpack 4 `package.js` - broken revision](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/vue-autocompletion/blob/0ffee3baa139a2f0e011ecfdaf672367889d8bbc/package.json)

[webpack 4 `webpackge.config.js`  - broken revision](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/vue-autocompletion/blob/0ffee3baa139a2f0e011ecfdaf672367889d8bbc/webpack.config.js)

[webpack 4 `package.js` - working revision](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/vue-autocompletion/blob/2ef74e8f9575cfd6fc4d0138f48586e275871c6e/package.json)

[webpack 4 `webpack.config.js` - working revision](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/vue-autocompletion/blob/2ef74e8f9575cfd6fc4d0138f48586e275871c6e/webpack.config.js)

So to summarise to upgrade to 4 and have something like the broken revision config specifically `webpack.config.js` - is likely to lead to above -

Also the build in package.js has slightly different setup on working revision to execute `npm run build`

Comment: So it turns out the issue is around me trying to use webpack4 but this only happened because npm suggested it was vulnerability, obviously as with everything these days your version 3 of webpack.config.js no longer works with webpack ver 4 and documentation around how you get all this to work is hard to come by. what is there didn't help reverting back but obviously vulnerabilities.

Comment: this is no longer an issue - want to close but is useful to know why

Answer (score 1):

You can import and register VueAutocompletion locally in your Vue component.

```
import VueAutocompletion from 'vue-autocompletion'
export default {
   components: {
      VueAutocompletion 
   },
   data () {
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your codes, the registered component name `vue-autocompletion` and used name in template `vue-auto-completion` are different from each other.

They should be the same.

```
<vue-auto-completion
...
components: {
  'vue-auto-completion':VueAutocompletion
},
```

Comment: Its not this  - I have put up a demo project here  https://github.com/vahidhedayati/vue-autocompletion-test - feel free to download and run `npm run dev`   actual vue page doing call is here https://github.com/vahidhedayati/vue-autocompletion-test/blob/master/src/components/Welcome.vue